# Coded UI Tests automation

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I want to automate the process of running coded UI tests.
Do i need to have user logged in to the system?
Or is it possible to run it using XYNT service?

Answer (score 2):

We are able to run our coded ui tests in an automated fashion using windows scheduler and the command line MSTest.exe. Take a look at the following MSDN article on how to accomplish this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx

I believe you can use Microsoft's Test Manager to accomplish this as well but we don't have TFS (yet) so I can't vouch for it.

Comment: +1 for above answer, another good link is: `http://www.matthewbussa.com/2010/10/how-to-run-coded-ui-tests-from-command.html`. Mark the above answer correct if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, CodedUI Tests require an active desktop session, so running them under a service account without an open desktop session may work, but not without a session.

Answer (score 1):

I used the mstest to run the coded ui test and use Windows TaskScheduler to schedule the test.
You can find detail in [MSTest.exe command-line documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

When you want to run it automatically, there are two things you should pay attention:
1. Set auto log on
2. Close the screen saver

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the snapshot of your enviroment with user logged in and then you can run your test through MS Test Manager or TFS (nightly build process)

Answer (score 0):

Write the test's in Visual Studio 2010/2012, this means you can manually edit the test's the code, then you should run them in Test Manager,

BTW you need TFS and Test Manager to be the same year otherwise it **won't** work.

I've being doing a lot of these recently if you have any questions post it online and send me a message, I'll be happy to help.